# Find the total number of balls in the bag

Tags: probability

> In a bag there are 10 to 20 red balls and some balls of other colours. If a ball is taken out randomly, that ball is red $\frac37$ of the time. What is the total number of balls in the bag?

I don't know how this should be done hence I don't have any progress to show. Your hints shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HINT*: If there are $q$ balls, $p$ of which are red, the probability that a red ball gets drawn is $\frac pq=\frac37$. $p$ and $q$ are whole numbers, so $q$ must be a multiple of 7. What multiple of 7 lies between 10 and 20?

Comment: 14 is that multiple of 7?

Comment: @user366082 Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If we are given that there are $n$ balls in the bag, how many red balls are there?

Comment: $n-\frac57$ it would be so now the total no of balls would be

Comment: @user366082:  Is that a typo?  $1-\frac 37=\frac 47$, not $\frac 57$.  The fraction should be multiplied by $n$ in any case.  Try harder.